# Run countdown timers one after another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to create a countdown website which runs a set of schedules as countdowns one after another. Each schedule is an array of a pair of strings which represent the start time and end time of each schedule.

**Expected Behaviour:**

I want the second schedule to start when the first one ends.

**Current Behaviour:**

After the first schedule is completed, the date shown on the webpage shows `NaN` for all the values.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong as I am new to programming.

[**Codepen of Minimum Complete Verifiable Example**](https://codepen.io/alivim/pen/RyVJKy) [You may have to change the start time and end times of the schedules to be in the future depending on when you open it to reproduce the issue]

Code Sample:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  clock.style.display = 'block';
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

// var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', schedule);

var schedule = [
    ['2018-05-01', '2018-05-02 13:36:00'],
    ['2018-05-02 13:36:01', '2018-05-09']
];

// iterate over each element in the schedule
for(var i=0; i<schedule.length; i++){
  var startDate = schedule[i][0];
  var endDate = schedule[i][1];

  // put dates in milliseconds for easy comparisons
  var startMs = Date.parse(startDate);
  var endMs = Date.parse(endDate);
  var currentMs = Date.parse(new Date());

  // if current date is between start and end dates, display clock
  if(endMs > currentMs && currentMs >= startMs ){
      initializeClock('clockdiv', endDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add logger in your methods to find out the errors

Answer (score 1):

The problem I think is mainly in two areas:

1. The for loop runs only once so the second schedule is never started after the first one ends (the for loop would have obviously finished executing and does not startup again). That loop should ideally run again once the first schedule ends.
2. The function to clear the timeout should be moved before the DOM update as the function `getTimeRemaining` may return inconsistent values when the schedule is over.

Solutions:

1. Wrap the schedule start code in a function `startNewScheduleIfNeeded` and run that new function each time a schedule ends and we clear the timer
2. Move the check to see if we should clear the timer above the DOM update in `updateClock` to avoid `NaN` values

Sample Code:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
        total: t,
        days: days,
        hours: hours,
        minutes: minutes,
        seconds: seconds
    };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    clock.style.display = "block";
    var daysSpan = clock.querySelector(".days");
    var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector(".hours");
    var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector(".minutes");
    var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector(".seconds");

    function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
        // Solution Part 2: Move check before DOM update and return early if needed
        if (t.total <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timeinterval);
            // Schedule has ended, run function to start another if needed.
            startNewScheduleIfNeeded();
            return;
        }
        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ("0" + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ("0" + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ("0" + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    }

    updateClock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

// var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
//initializeClock('clockdiv', schedule);

// Solution Part 1: Wrap schedule start in a function to resuse when schedules end
function startNewScheduleIfNeeded() {
    var schedule = [
        ["2018-05-03", "2018-05-03 11:17:00"],
        ["2018-05-03 11:17:00", "2018-05-09"]
    ];

    // iterate over each element in the schedule
    for (var i = 0; i < schedule.length; i++) {
        var startDate = schedule[i][0];
        var endDate = schedule[i][1];

        // put dates in milliseconds for easy comparisons
        var startMs = Date.parse(startDate);
        var endMs = Date.parse(endDate);
        var currentMs = Date.parse(new Date());

        // if current date is between start and end dates, display clock
        if (endMs > currentMs && currentMs >= startMs) {
            initializeClock("clockdiv", endDate);
        }
    }
}
startNewScheduleIfNeeded();
```

Other observations:

1. there was a random call to `initializeClock` which I have commented out
2. You only need to use `Date.parse` if your input is a string (like your schedule list). calling `Date.parse(new Date())` is redundant. You can just use `new Date()`. Also, `Date.parse` DOES NOT return an integer (milliseconds). It returns a Date object which gets casted to a number when you do comparison like `<`
3. The end time of one schedule must be equal to the start time in the next schedule for this method to work. If you have gaps (even one second) the function to start the schedule will execute before the check to see if the current time is between the start time and end time can pass. (in the example in your question, end time of first schedule is `'2018-05-02 13:36:00'` and the start time for the next one is `'2018-05-02 13:36:01'`. This won't work - the start time of the second schedule has to be `'2018-05-02 13:36:00'`).